# How to fix the "Android MPAndroidChart Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments error in gradle"?

Tags: android, gradle, mpandroidchart

well Im trying to use MPAndroidChart library in Android studio
my gradle version was 7.0.2 but it didnt work well.
so i changed gradle Version to 6.7.1, and Android Gradle Plugin Version to 4.2.2
i also changed the version of sdk to Android 11.0(R)
my Target SDK version is 30

**--build.gradle(project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-

projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects{
    repositories{
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**--build.gradle(Module)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31
    BuildToolsVersion '30.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
repositories{
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
}
```

**--setting.gradle**

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'
```

**--capture of the bug**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9NvK.png)

**--bug code**
Settings file 'C:\Users\kimta\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\settings.gradle' line: 1

A problem occurred evaluating settings 'MyApplication'.

> Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments [settings_5pc4jcjs87c9dkfx5manehm0u$_run_closure1@69c68d91] on settings 'MyApplication' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.

gradle problem is too difficult for novice like me. Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You try to add this line in your `settings.gradle`:

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

**--setting.gradle**

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }  //Add this line in your settings.gradle
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'
```

**--build.gradle(project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**--build.gradle(Module)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // MPAndroidChart
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
}
```

Comment: thank you so much Jermy Caney. and hoanglam0869